# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resources/properties/database.properties]

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i build now a web application with spring and Java EE but i got one exception. I try to read the value from the properties file. I have a properties folder in the resources folder and the servlet-context.xml is into WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/

```
<context:property-placeholder location="resources/properties/database.properties" /><context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />
```

i tried another alternative with the classpath but nothing:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/properties/database.properties" />
```

When i run apache tomcat:

```
Nov 18, 2014 10:28:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet /spring threw load() exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resources/properties/database.properties]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4007)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1524)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 18, 2014 10:28:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMATION: Reloading Context with name [/spring] is completed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using maven for building your war file from the source code? If so, then I would assume that the resources directory you mentioned above is under src directory of your maven project.

For this case you would need to have the following declaration in spring context xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/database.properties" />
```